# AngularJS Error: $injector:nomod Module Unavailable

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to learn AngularJS and am creating my first page. I am encountering the error:

Error: $injector:nomod Module Unavailable ([here](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=Error:%20%5B$injector:nomod%5D%20http:%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.4.4%2F$injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3DmyApp%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Error%20(native)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.4%2Fangular.min.js:6:416%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.4%2Fangular.min.js:24:78%0A%20%20%20%20at%20a%20(https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.4%2Fangular.min.js:23:141)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Q.bootstrap%20(https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.4%2Fangular.min.js:23:384)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.4%2Fangular.min.js:37:402%0A%20%20%20%20at%20m%20(https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.4%2Fangular.min.js:7:322)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.4%2Fangular.min.js:37:180)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20eb%20(https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.4%2Fangular.min.js:40:435)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20d%20(https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.4%2Fangular.min.js:19:381))

I have three files:

```
/index.html
/js/app.js
/js/controllers/MainController.js
```

And they are as follows:

### /index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <tilte>AngularJS Controllers</title>
        <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-app="myApp">
            <h1>Controllers</h1>
            <div ng-controller="MainController">
                <p>{{ message }}</p>
                <form ng-submit="updateMessage(newMessage)">
                    <input type="text" ng-model="newMessage">
                    <button type="submit">Update Message</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Modules -->
        <script type="text/javascript" scr="js/app.js"></script>

        <!-- Controllers -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers/MainController.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

### /js/app.js

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
```

### /js/controllers/MainController.js

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.message = 'hello';

    $scope.updateMessage = function(message){
        $scope.message = message;
    };
}]);
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a typo.
When you pull your `app.js` inside the html, you wrote `scr` instead of `src`.
See:

```
<!-- Modules -->
<script type="text/javascript" scr="js/app.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Avoid creating global variables like app for assigning the angular module. Instead angular provides a better syntax to set and get modules across multiple files.

## App.js

```
(function() {
    // IIFE (Immediately invoked Function Express) to wrap variables inside the function. it prevents polluting global namespace.
     angular.module("myApp", []);
})();
```

## MainController

```
  (function() {
     angular.module("myApp") // note [] is missing, it means we're getting a module
        .controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope){
            $scope.message = 'hello';

            $scope.updateMessage = function(message){
               $scope.message = message;
             };
        }]);
    })();
```

Comment: I have changed my files to this, but I am still getting the same error

Comment: Thank you for your help though, I will use this from now on